# time dependance of ip-based geolocation accuracy

Tags: networking, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I'm using ipinfo.io to look up geolocation data of a list of IP addresses that have accessed my database over the course of nearly two years. I'm curious about the time-dependance on the accuracy of the geolocation data.

For example, suppose someone accessed my server from an IP address in January 2017. Is it possible that when I look up that address now (December 2018) that I get a different result than if I had looked it up in January of 2017?

Comment: Geolocation of IP addresses can be pretty inaccurate, anyway. For example, many of the geolocation databases think I am over 1000 miles from my actual location because that is where my ISP's headquarters are. Some companies doing business in less desirable parts of the world will use U.S. based IP addressing to prevent being blacklisted. If you understand that using geolocation can return crap information, then you can use it, but do not depend on the results for anything important.

Comment: I'm aware that it can be pretty inaccurate. This question is aimed at finding out if it is even less accurate after time has passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. IP address allocation required yearly renewal, else it will be reallocated to other owners. Some ISP will also reassign their IP address to different location frequently within their network.

In this case, you should not use the 2018 database for 2017 IP addresses.